# macOS ctrl+a can't select all in Chrome Google website search box, command+a also doesn't not work

Tags: macos

macOS version is 12.4.

I tried to set <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> as select all for all applications in preference but it just not working.

Currently the behavior for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is moving cursor to beginning and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to end.

On the other hand, for other text, it seems <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> is working.

Please help me if you have experienced this before.

Comment: Stop trying to fight global key commands. You will fail, as you've already discovered. Vive la difference.

Comment: @Tetsujin but even command-a also not working for the search box, I have to manually click x button to clear the text, I'm tired for this

Comment: Once you've started playing with key commands, trying to change global defaults, it's not surprising you get inconsistent behaviour. Macs *do* use Ctrl, but not as the *main* modifier. Ctrl/A is 'go to top of line'. Cmd/A, triple-click, or Cmd L will select all the omni-bar contents.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks to your advisement, I think I have understood the situation correctly now. I used crtl-a as select all which disable command-a but itself was used for 'go to top of the line', so there is no select all shortcut actually. This should be the inconsistent behavior you talked about. Thanks for save me arm to click the x button anymore.